# EntityFramework + Sql Server + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework

Olá, tenho uma aplicação em ASP.NET MVC que está utilizando o ORM EntityFramework para fazer a comunicação com um banco SQL Server!

Atualmente troquei de computador e tive que instalar tudo de novo, Visual Studio, e SQL Server Management. Porém ao iniciar a aplicação teria que criar as tabelas usando o migrations para o SQL Server com o comando 'update-database'.. Porem ao realizar esse comando, o seguinte erro aparece:

***A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)***

Falando que a base não é encontrada. Porem minha connectionString aponta exatamente para o banco atual, pois peguei essa connectionString da própria conexão do visual Studio pelo 'SQL Server Object Explorer'

***ConnectionString***

```html
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BWSDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-PTI280V;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que devo fazer?
Agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo é preferência...

A sua *connection string* tem o nome da máquina mas não tem o nome da instância. Tente usar localhost\SQLEXPRESS no seu Data Source, onde tem o SQLEXPRESS, no exemplo trata-se do nome da sua instância. Mas se eu não estiver enganado, pode ser só a falta do parâmetro database ("*..;Database=BWSDatabase;..*").

O nome da sua instância existem formas simples de verificar.

Acessando *services.msc* pelo prompt de comando, você pode ver o nome da sua instância ao lado do nome do serviço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se preferir, pode ver direto do *Management Studio*...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas por padrão, uso:

```
connectionString="Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BWSDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=senha;"
```

Comment: Boa, apenas com o parâmetro 'Database' funcionou, porém é bom deixar com o server, pois quando for utilizar em um servidor externo dai vai ser necessário.